# Storing/adding a non predefined number of values from a single input (Python)

Tags: python, variables, input, int

I am writing a small programm for a school assingment and for this assingment we have to input multiple values and then add them. The only problem is the number of values isn't predefined so a line such as

`a, b, c, d = input("Enter four numbers separated by commas: ").split(',')`

won't work because the number of varibles isn't pre defined. Now my question was if there is a way to input a number of ints in a single input and then add them. I want somthing along the lines of

```
Xnumber_of_varibles = input("enter x number of numbers separrated by comma's").split(',')
X1+x2+x3+x4 etc = awnser
```

I also thought about making a loop but this would be a lot of work so i thought there might be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map()` function to convert the string to integers and then use the `sum()` function to add them all

So Try this:

```
a = raw_input("enter x number of numbers separated by comma's").split(',') 
answer = sum(map(int,a))
print answer
```

Comment: I know you just used the input line that OP wrote, but that should be raw_input, not input.

Comment: And it should indeed be raw_input my mistake

Comment: @KDawG Tags? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Cyber I thpught the OP was on python 3 where raw_input was replaced with `input` but looks like the OP is on 2.7 after all

Comment: @KDawG Oh, good call. I didn't even think to look at the version they were using.

Comment: @user3157264 I thought you were on python 3 BTW feel [free to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and upvote if this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with looping. For loops auto-iterate. I will break up an example below so you can see the steps involved.

```
user_values = raw_input("enter x number of numbers separrated by comma's\n")
variable_list = user_values.split(",")
sum = 0
for i in variable_list:
    sum += int(i)
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using raw_input to read from console, plus map function combined with int function to convert the input numbers to int (via the int function) and them sum it with the sum function:

```
numbers_input = raw_input("Enter x number of numbers separated by comma:").split(',') 
print sum(map(int, numbers_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided are fine.  It is important to note that split returns a list.  Most importantly, you should alway program defensively and validate user input with try/except blocks or other validation.

```
variables = input("Enter x number of numbers separated by a comma").split(',')

sum = 0
for val in variables:
    try:
        sum = sum + int(val)
    except:
        print "Entered values must be integers: " + str(val)

print “Sum = “ + str(sum)
```